# Pushing Changes to Existing Heroku Registry

Tags: docker, heroku, heroku-cli

I created a web app and hosted it on Heroku a while ago.  I basically wrote a dockerfile with all the instructions and followed steps like [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#building-and-pushing-image-s).  I just now opened my old laptop and made changes to some of the code.  I tried to follow the same steps as usual to push changes, but when I run `heroku container:push web -a bluebird-teaching` (the app is called bluebird-teaching), I get a strange error.

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

I made sure that I'm logged in on Heroku CLI and my app still runs.  The name of the app on Heroku is indeed the same name I'm putting in the tag (not sure of that matters).  I can't just do `heroku create` because that's going to create a whole new app.  I would just like to push changes to an existing app.  Any ideas how I could do what I'm trying to do?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker is not running on your old laptop.

The `heroku container:push` builds and pushes the image as defined in the Dockerfile: this needs the Docker deamon to run.

Comment: 10/10!  My old laptop is a Mac.  I knew I had docker installed obviously because I had done this before on the same laptop.  I knew that Mac has a GUI version so I opened it and there turned out to be an update.  I updated Docker, and I was able to do container:push!